# RDKIT export dataframe to .mol or .sdf file

Tags: pandas, rdkit, molecule

I need to convert a bunch of Smiles into mold2 using this GUI tools (https://www.fda.gov/files/science%20&%20research/published/Mold2-Tutorial.pdf)

How do I convert pandas data frame into either `.mol` or `.sdf` file?

Comment: Did you try `PandasTools.WriteSDF()` in RDKit?

Comment: I did but then it is not working in the Mold2 GUI software. 

The main goal is to convert smiles to mold2

Comment: Did you figure this out yet? The [rdkit tag at MMSE](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rdkit) has 95.5% of its questions answered. If you want this question migrated there, please ping me by typing @Nike in a comment and letting me know. I'll make a case to the moderators for a migration.

Comment: @Nike, yes please

Comment: @Petr questions can only be migrated within 60 days. The only thing you can do now is to ask the question at MMSE in a new (separate) post and provide a link to this question there.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer = SDWriter('out.sdf')
for mol in list_of_mols:
    writer.write(mol)
```

rdkit has documentation for this here [rdkit docs](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/source/rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.html#rdkit.Chem.rdmolfiles.SDWriter)